# How to get contrasting colours for vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am using vim 8.0 on Windows 10.

It is the vim that came with my git bash.

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Oct 12 2016 13:28:14)
```

I'm sure I never changed the default settings, but the syntax highlighting for C/C++ is truly atrocious because it lacks contrast with the background.

I have good vision, but e.g. the pragma's are far too dark to read on a black background.

So I figured the highlighting was meant to go on a white background, and changed my terminal window to be white.

This made it even worse, and other parts of the source code lose all their contrast with the background.

[image]

Quick! What's the name of the define in this source code? Indeed...

How was VIM's syntax highlighting intended? For black backgrounds? If so, why does it lack contrast?

What's the best remedy for this? Is there a fix that does not involve me tuning the colours myself?

Comment: Download a color scheme you like better?

Comment: ... or try the ones you already have: `:colorscheme <CTRL-D>`

Comment: @melpomene Thanks. That's the correct answer. `:colorscheme blue` for the win.